# What are masked assertions in Microsoft Code Contracts?

Tags: c#, code-contracts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to find 'masked' assertions in MS Code Contracts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10037797/how-to-find-masked-assertions-in-ms-code-contracts)

I started with Code Contracts under C# 4.0 recently and I get messages like the following:

```
CodeContracts: Checked 50 assertions: 33 correct (17 masked)
```

I've been looking all over to find out what a masked assertion is, but have not found it. It is not in the CodeContracts manual, nor could I find anything on 'masked assertion'.

Any insight?

Comment: I don't have any 'baseline' functionality enabled, so the answer in the possible duplicate is not correct as far as I can see. I don't have baseline checked, nor can I find any baseline.xml file in my source or build tree.

Comment: I get these messages on a completely clean build. Unless these baseline files are stored outside of my source tree, something else is going on...

Comment: A completely clean build with "cache results" = off for static checking still gives masked assertions

Comment: For the record, this is not a duplicate...